# PHP touch(): Unable to create file because of invalid arguments

Tags: php

I have this following $path:

P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/_moduletest_tmp_\P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/**_***lock*____

but when i ran this code:

```
touch($path);
```

I get this error:

```
Warning     touch(): Unable to create file P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/_moduletest_tmp_\P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/______lock_____ because Invalid argument on line 733 in file P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\module-test.php
```

line 733 is this:

```
touch($path);
```

Any suggestions how to resolved this? I'm running XAMPP under Windows using PHP 5.4.17.Thanks.

Comment: why is it calling two directories? `P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/_moduletest_tmp_\P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/______lock_____`

Comment: You've got / in your directory, windows uses \ to show different folders and by the looks of it, two paths in the variable. Check your path by copying and pasting the directory tree into your explorer. If it doesn't go to where you want, it's not correct.

Comment: @13ruce1337..yes that was strange..

Comment: @Impulss, yes I'll do this test..

Comment: @Impulss I was looking at `P:` thats called twice. I've seen `/` to escape certain things before. normally the `:` means a drive.

Comment: \ Is is escape character, but that's not escaping anything

Comment: @13ruce1337. If the file should be inside _moduletest_tmp_ this should be the correct path in windows right? P:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\_modulemanager_tmp_\______lock_____

Comment: You should be using / for directories in windows. You also need a / for the last directory, between the file name and the last directory. Use the code that @bprayudha provided. Should work nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $path = 'P:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/';
  touch("$path" . "_moduletest_tmp_");
  touch("$path" . "_lock____");
```

Make sure directory `P:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/` is exist.

Comment: if it doesn't it will create it: [If the file does not exist, it will be created.](http://php.net/touch)

Comment: No. `touch` in PHP is like on Unix. It will not create the file if the directory doesn't exist.